# Как правильно сгенерировать сертификат для настойки https на nginx?

Tags: nginx, https, openssl

Я хочу создай свой сертификат для настройки https на nginx,  в интернету есть много примеров для генерации сертификатов, даже нашел вот этот [инструмент](https://certificatetools.com/newui/).
Проблема заключается в том что при попытке перейти по адресу я получаю ошибку от Chromium.

```
Перейти на сайт example.net невозможно, так как его  
идентификационные данные зашифрованы, и Chrome не может их  
обработать. Это могло произойти из-за ошибки сети или атаки на сайт.  
Скорее всего, он заработает через некоторое время.
```

Сам сертификат я добавил в браузере в "центры сертификации", но ошибка осталась.

Файл конфигурации nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.net;

    ssl_certificate           /ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /ssl/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/fines-auth.log;

    location /auth {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://0.0.0.0:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://0.0.0.0:3000 https://example.net;
}
```

}

Comment: Я бы выкинул 4 строчки после ssl on и поставил сертификат от let's encrypt. Он работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Источник: http://blog.regolit.com/2010/02/16/personal-ca-and-self-signed-certificates

1. Создание ключа для центра сертификации (CA) 
   `$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096`
2. Создание сертификата для CA
   `$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`
3. Создание ключа для сервера
   `$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096`
4. Создание сертификата для сервера
   4.1 Конфиг-файл для openssl, сохраняем в текущей папке под именем openssl-csr.cnf

   ```
   ###############################################
   # Remaining options below  should not be edited
   ###############################################

   [ req ]
   default_bits = 4096
   distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
   req_extensions     = req_ext

   [ req_distinguished_name ]
   countryName                  = Country Name (2 letter code)
   countryName_default          = RU
   stateOrProvinceName          = State or Province Name (full name)
   stateOrProvinceName_default  = Russia
   localityName                 = Locality Name (eg, city)
   localityName_default         = Irkutsk
   organizationName             = Organization Name (eg, company)
   organizationName_default     = Example, Co.
   commonName                   = Common Name (eg, YOUR name or FQDN)
   commonName_max               = 64

   [ req_ext ]
   basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
   keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

   ###############################################
   # Edit this line to set subjectAltName contents
   ###############################################
   subjectAltName          = DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com, DNS:example.net
   ```

   4.2 Генерация сертификата
   `$ openssl req -new -key server.key -config openssl-csr.cnf -reqexts req_ext -out server.csr`
5. Подпись серверного сертификата, сертификатом CA
   `$ openssl x509 -req -days 365  -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -extfile openssl-csr.cnf -extensions req_ext -in server.csr -out server.crt`

Файлы server.(csr,key) - подключаются к серверу
Файл ca.csr - нужно добавить в браузер в центры сертификации